# CakePHP virtual field giving internal error

Tags: php, cakephp, model, cakephp-2.3, cakephp-model

In my Delivery model I have the following virtual field set:

```
public $virtualFields = array(
  'shoe_count' => 'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM shoes as Shoe WHERE Shoe.delivery_id = Delivery.id'
);
```

When I remove this, everything works fine. Upon adding the shoe_count virtual field, I get the following error on any method of the Shoe controller:

> An Internal Error Has Occurred. Error: An Internal Error Has Occurred.

[image]

Comment: You are using `Delivery.id` is your SQL request without selecting from this table !

Comment: Also it would be better to use counterCache instead instead of doing this count query over and over. It's not efficient.

Comment: Change debug mode to `Configure::write('debug', 1)` to show errors. put this line in AppController.php 's beforeFilter() function.

Answer (score 0):

In your php or cake errorlog you should find what causes this error, it could be that there is a Problem with Delivery.Id because in your example I do not see where this value should come from... but yeah you should first lock inside the errorlog